# Python Multi indexing calculations

Tags: python, indexing, group-by

I have a dataframe with many securities ( sedols) and many dates (carry_dt) during which that security was traded. I would like to loop through every sedol, and categorize that trade based on prior dates. I want to classify each trade by 3 categories:

1. first - the first instance of the security,
2. no change - the carry_rate on this day matches the priors dates carry_rate,
3. adjustment - the dates carry_rate differs from the prior date.

Below is a snapshot of how my dataframe looks. Type is a column that I would need added to the dataframe

```
     carry_dt  carry_rate    sedol        type
0    2/8/2018        1.42  BZ6C639       first
1    2/9/2018        1.42  BZ6C639   no change
2   2/10/2018        1.42  BZ6C639   no change
3   2/11/2018        1.42  BZ6C639   no change
4   2/12/2018        1.50  BZ6C639  adjustment
5   2/13/2018        1.50  BZ6C639   no change
6   2/14/2018        1.70  BZ6C639  adjustment
7   2/15/2018        1.42  1234243       first
8   2/16/2018        1.42  1234243   no change
9   2/17/2018        1.42  1234243   no change
10  2/18/2018        1.42  1234243   no change
11  2/19/2018        1.42  1234243   no change
12  2/20/2018        1.90  1234243  adjustment
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your data as test, not as an image or link. For example, try `df.head()`. See also [mcve].

Comment: I need to know the formula using presumably multindexing to calculate the type column

Comment: dataset.head()
Out[116]: 
   carry_dt  carry_rate    sedol 
0  1/2/2018        0.15  BP41ZD1          
2  1/2/2018        0.15  2371823      
3  1/2/2018        0.15  2369389       
4  1/2/2018        0.15  2502139

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) with [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
s = df.groupby('sedol')['carry_rate'].diff()

df['type'] = np.select([s == 0, s.isnull()], ['no change', 'first'], default='adjustment')
print (df)
     carry_dt  carry_rate    sedol        type
0    2/8/2018        1.42  BZ6C639       first
1    2/9/2018        1.42  BZ6C639   no change
2   2/10/2018        1.42  BZ6C639   no change
3   2/11/2018        1.42  BZ6C639   no change
4   2/12/2018        1.50  BZ6C639  adjustment
5   2/13/2018        1.50  BZ6C639   no change
6   2/14/2018        1.70  BZ6C639  adjustment
7   2/15/2018        1.42  1234243       first
8   2/16/2018        1.42  1234243   no change
9   2/17/2018        1.42  1234243   no change
10  2/18/2018        1.42  1234243   no change
11  2/19/2018        1.42  1234243   no change
12  2/20/2018        1.90  1234243  adjustment
```

Detail:

```
print (s)
0      NaN
1     0.00
2     0.00
3     0.00
4     0.08
5     0.00
6     0.20
7      NaN
8     0.00
9     0.00
10    0.00
11    0.00
12    0.48
Name: carry_rate, dtype: float64
```